# Pure geometry proof of parabola property.

Tags: conic-sections

Is there a way to prove the property of the parabola that a ray parallel to its axis of symmetry if "reflected" by the parabola will intersect the symmetry axis of the parabola, without using analytic geometry?
[image]

Assuming that $DA\parallel CB$ and that the line has been reflected,I want to prove that B is in fact the focus of the parabola.

Comment: Idea/Hint: it suffices to show that, if the intersection of the parallel ray with the directrix is $E$, then $\triangle EAB$ is isoceles, and the tangent to the parabola at $A$ either bisects $BE$ or is perpendicular to it (either is sufficient to give two congruent right-angled triangles).

Comment: There's one at http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa08/Wisdom/EMAT6690/Parabolanjw/reflectiveproperty.htm , found at  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351498/pure-geometry-proof-of-parabolic-mirror-property

Comment: Would you mind a proof that just uses equation of  a line ?

Comment: Undermines the point, man.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be focus of parabola.

It is well known that if we project orthogonal any point $P$ on parabola to it directrix we get such point $P'$ on directrix, that perpendicular bisector $t$ of $FP'$ is tangent of parabola at $P$. Thus if we reflect $PG$ across $t$ we get parallel through $P$ to axis of symmetry of parabola.

So if we reverse this process, we see that if reflect parallel to axis of symmetry at point $P$ on parabola, this reflection must go through $F$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756391/tangent-on-parabola-bisects-angle